# Find unique row when two rows when two row have the column id as the same, but have other column a date which I want the newset one

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Create a query of unique values, but some of them have same ids but different dates. Just want the newest date. I am joining several tables, but do not know how to handle this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap.id, MAX(ap.date) 
FROM sometable;
```

I tried this code but no result.

I get these resulst:

```
id date
------------
1  10/31/18
1  10/15/18
2  11/05/17
2  11/04/17
```

But I want these results:

```
1  10/31/18
2  11/05/17
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  group by

```
SELECT ap.id, MAX(ap.date) 
from sometable ap
group by ap.id;
```

the aggregation function as min(), max() ,, count() need  group by for return the related  agreagated  result

and for the query in you comment you should use

```
SELECT ap.id, MAX(ap.date) 
from sometable ap
where ap.id in ( id1, id2, id3.... idns) 
group by ap.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I tried that also my exactly query is like:
SELECT ap.id, MAX(ap.date) 
from sometable where in (many ids)
group by ap.id
got not a single-group group function error :(

Comment: @JuanCarlosLujan  answer  updated  for a suggestion realted to the query you posted in comment.  Anyway you should not post a question with a code different from the code you are exactly using  .. we are not in your mind and why can only answer  a waht we can see in your question  ...

Answer (score 0):

In case your query has other columns too that you want to show in result, you will have to resort to analytical function, in such case your query will look like following

```
select id, the_date /* ,other columns */ from (
    select  row_number() over (partition by id 
            order by some_date /* your date column */ desc ) ord, 
    id, 
    some_date the_date    
    /* ,other columns */
    from <your_table>
) where ord = 1
;
```